# Process query in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, sqldatareader

I want to convert the result returned by data reader to objects. When I query the data and group it by some field, I find that I am not taking advantage of the ordered data when I try to convert it to a list of objects which each object being the set of rows matching a group by relationship. Using linq might help, but I find it is like regrouping the data and not taking advantage that the query result is already ordered. Does anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: You should show your code. Difficult to give any guidance without it.

Answer (score 0):

If the grouping must be done after the data has been returned from the SQL query (e.g. because the grouping is dynamic) then you should remove the order by from the SQL query and move it to the Linq instead. Otherwise, do the grouping in the SQL query along with the ordering. The point is, both operations should be done in the same place at the same time.

Comment: It is being done in the SQL and I have the data reader with the data already ordered, as would be expected from a query operation, the issue that i don't find an easy way about how to take advantage of that data being ordered when converting it to a list of object representation.

Comment: Please add some code showing how the data reader is being mapped to the list.